# Usage of ellipse in synopsis of command line argument

Tags: man

From http://pubs.opengroup.org/stage7tc1/basedefs/V1_chap12.html

> Ellipses ( "..." ) are used to denote that one or more occurrences of
> an operand are allowed. When an option or an operand followed by
> ellipses is enclosed in brackets, zero or more options or operands can
> be specified. The form:
>
> ```
> utility_name [-g option_argument]...[operand...]
> ```
>
> indicates that multiple occurrences of the option and its
> option-argument preceding the ellipses are valid, with semantics as
> indicated in the OPTIONS section of the utility. (See also Guideline
> 11 in Utility Syntax Guidelines .)
>
> The form:
>
> ```
> utility_name -f option_argument [-f option_argument]... [operand...]
> ```
>
> indicates that the -f option is required to appear at least once and
> may appear multiple times.

1. Are there differences between the order of bracket and ellipses?
   Do `[something]...` and `[something...]` both mean repeating zero or more times?
2. Do `something [something]...` and `something...` both  mean the same as repeating once or more times?

Comment: 1. Yes and no. Note above `[-g opt_arg]...` and `[operand...]`. For `-g` you must specify an argument, but you can apparently specify `-g` and its opt_arg as many times as you like. For the `operand` there is no such fixed pair requirement.

Comment: As the first sentence states, `...` (no brackets) means *one or more* whereas `[...]` means *zero or more*.

Comment: @Tim; there **is** a difference in the semantics if there is more than one entity in the brackets, e.g. in case of `[-f arg]`, where `[-f arg]...` would indicate multiple pairs (like `-f opt1 -f opt2`) while `[-f arg...]` would mean multiple args (like `-f opt1 opt2`).

Answer (score 3):

- `[-f option_argument]...` means that the optional `-f` option may occur several times, each time with an option argument.  It would allow for e.g. `-f a -f b -f c`.
- `[-f option_argument...]` is nonsensical as an option can only have one argument. It would allow for `-f a b c` which is really `-f` with the option argument `a` followed by the two operands `b` and `c`.
- `[operand...]` denotes one or several optional operands. This would allow for `a b c`.
- `[operand]...` would mean "this optional operand, several times".  This would be something like `a a a` but not `a b c`.

Comment: re. "`[operand]...` would mean `a a a`", that seems like an odd interpretation. Shouldn't it mean that `[-f option_argument]...` could also only be e.g. `-f a -f a` and not `-f a -f b`?

Comment: @ilkkachu Hmm... Looking back at this three years later, it does look a bit odd. However, I can't find any instance of `[operand]...` in the utilities on my system, which means that this is probably as non-sensical as `[-f option_argument...]`.

Comment: I didn't look through all of it, but figured they'd use `[operand...]` everywhere, if only to be consistent... As far as I can read a technical interpretation of that, it seems the distinction would be similar to `(a)*` vs `(a+)?` in regex, i.e. no real difference.

Comment: @ilkkachu I was more thinking `(RE)*` vs. `(RE)\1*`